# Error creating foreign key on <TableName> (check data types)

Tags: mysql

I want to create to tables in mysql, te first table is called Catégorie and the second is called Article as :

(Article) 0..* ------------- 1 (Catégorie)

but I get this error :

> Error creating foreign key on idCat (check data types)

and this is the code I tried :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Catégorie` (
  `idCat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `libCat` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCat`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Article` (
  `codeArt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `desgArt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `etatArt` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qteArt` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `qteseulmin` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idCat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codeArt`),
  KEY `idCat` (`idCat`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE  `Article` ADD FOREIGN KEY (  `idCat` ) REFERENCES  `GestionStock`.`Catégorie` (
`idCat`
) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE ;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You declared column `Article.idCat` as **NOT NULL**, and then you are trying to create foreign key with ON DELETE **SET NULL** action.

Change column or foreign key definition.

Answer (score 7):

One of the reasons for this error is incompatible data types.

For example, in my case, the problem was that while the actual id was 'UNSIGNED', the foreign key referring to it was not declared unsigned. Hence the latter's scope was higher.

Note that the opposite can work.

Answer (score 2):

In your table definitions, you've said that idCat can never be NULL.

However, your key definition is trying to say that idCat should be set to NULL on a DELETE operation.

These requirements are incompatible, hence the error.

Answer (score -1):

ALTER TABLE  `Article` ADD FOREIGN KEY (  `idCat` ) REFERENCES  `GestionStock`.`language` (
`idCat`
) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;

Use Like this